# In app purchase: signature is ""

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

In **`purchaseStateChanged()`** I received signature as "" String, so I received bad response from our server, because it cannot verify the billing.

Why the signature is ""?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using making the purchase using the test product (`android.test.purchased`)? The test product will never send you back the signature to verify against - only purchasing an actual products will.

Comment: I tried to use both test and real products with my signed apk and only signed returns me not null signature. But on earlier version (billing v2, I was testing it about 3 or 4 months ago) it returned me not null signature with test products